# Hyperlink from hyperref package doesn't match with the content

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm trying to use the hyperref package in order to link my Table Of Content. But when I'm using it, the "hyperlink" doesn't match with the table's content (picture is provide below, surely better than a big explanation).
Any hint is welcome. Thanks :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\ProvidesPackage{pagegarde}
% Package image 
%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% Package couleur 
%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{miagecolor}{rgb}{0.129, 0.482, 0.541}

% Package mise en forme marge
%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage[margin=2,5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% Variables 
%\newcommand{\CouleurTitrePageGarde}{Emerald}

% Metadata
%-----------------------------------------
%\title{Rapport intermédiaire de stage}
%\author{Charles Canavaggio \thanks{Remerciement  à l'ensemble de la GRICS}}

%French-specific commands
%------------------------------
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint} % for the \nombre command

%Set the  font (output) encoding
%--------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Hyphenation rules
%-------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
%----------------------------------

% Encadrement autour de la page
%-----------------------------------
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
%-----------------------------------
% Package pour le style du sommaire 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%----------------------




\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% package hyper lien entre element du doc tmtc
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% Page de garde 
\import{./}{PageDeGarde.tex}

% Content 
% retire le numero de page 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{PAGE \thepage \hspace{1pt} }
% Change le nom de content 
\renewcommand\contentsname{\textbf{\textcolor{miagecolor}{SOMMAIRE}}}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace{-5.5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[]{images/Image2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
% INTRODUCTION 
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{INTRODUCTION}
\section*{INTRODUCTION}
Dans le cadre de mon cursus universitaire, j’ai réalisé un stage de fin d’étude au sein de la GRICS. La GRICS est un organisme à but non lucratif qui développe, adapte et soutient la plus vaste gamme de solution de gestion administrative, scolaire et pédagogique faites sur mesure pour le monde de l’éducation au Québec. 

J’ai été recruté afin de participer à l’amélioration du cycle MLOps, ainsi qu'au développent de la partie ethique des modèles. (fairness) 
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace{-6cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[]{images/Image2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\newpage
\section{MON STAGE}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\vspace{-3cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[]{images/Image2.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Objectif du stage et réalisation attendue}
bla bla bla 

\subsection{Plan de travail réalisé et previsionnel}
bla bla bl bal \\
bllb lbzllb 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section{Foreword}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section{Foreword}` should presumably be `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foreword}`. If that's not the cause of the problem, then we'll need a proper [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). The current code uses a non-standard package (`pagegarde.sty`), inputted files, and images that none of us have access to, and therefore we cannot test your code. Try to see if you can make the example not use any of those things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it appears that it come from the pagegarde.sty. It come from the part %encadrement autour de la page. I'll try to fix it